# Making the switch to gulp and have problems with susy

Tags: gulp, rpm, susy

Im making the change in workflow to use gulp and was setting up all my dependencies. I use SUSY to do grids and can get the latest version 3 installed. Unfortunately I have quite a few historic projects I still need to support that use SUSY 2. can anyone explain how I downgrade  my susy rpm to version 2

sorry if this is really easy but this work flow is new, running this on mac os and have node.js installed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

install susy locally for each project

```
npm install --save susy@2.x
```

this will install the latest version of susy2

Comment: that worked for me and now my mac is accepting sass through gulp thanks